# 18.04 Display resolution with new graphics driver

Tags: drivers, 18.04, screen, display-resolution

I recently added a 'new' graphics card (Radeon AMD HD 7470) and display is not as I want it. I In Screen Display I'm only able to chose between 4 display options, best of which is 1024 x 768. This isn't as good as what I was getting without the graphics card, where it was something like 1600 x ??. 
Right now display isn't as good, too blocky & large but I'm unable to change this in screen display.

I'm now running linux 18.04 (upgraded from 16.04 after I heard about AMD issues with 16.04- https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04 - but it's not made a difference in display. I tried card with 16.04 but display wasn't good so I upgraded to 18.04 hoping it'd be an improvement. It wasn't).

I've looked at proprietary Radeon AMD drivers but none are available for AMD HD 7470 beyond 15.04 (https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-amd-radeon-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)
I've run 
`lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'` 
which gives:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Caicos XT [Radeon HD 7470/8470 / R5 235/310 OEM] [1002:6778]
```

> xrandr returns the following:

```
> Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-0 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00* 
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94
```

Graphics card output is DVI-I which is connected to a VGA adapter going to the monitor (which annoyingly only has VGA input).

I have no idea where to go from hers so I'd appreciate any assistance you can provide.

Comment: Can you please show your `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` content?

Comment: Ok, It's fairly lengthy so here goes: Tried posting but it says '

too long by 26170 characters '. will have to post in pieces

Comment: @Hi-Angel It's only letting me post about 5 lines at a time here. Is there an easier way to post this file?

Comment: @Hi-Angel As I can't see a way to put /var/log/Xorg.0.log directly here I've put it on pastebin at https://pastebin.com/455st77j

Comment: Hmm… The log looks okay to me, I dunno, maybe it's something hardware related… Okay, you know, try joining IRC `#radeon` channel on Freenode, and asking there that you've got this shiny new card, and there's no resolution more than 1024×768. Be patient, it can take some time before anyone answer, and also that now is a weekend.